# how to make app a percent of the screen size

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to make my app look like the image below, but by setting my app as a percent of my whole screen (not setting the dp), so that no matter what type of phone I am using, the app will take up the same screen percentage. This is my main activity which just consists of two fragments in one LinearLayout. ﻿

```
android:layout_width="300dp"
android:layout_height="300dp"


xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:background="@drawable/rounded_edges"
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">

<!-- Create a container (FrameLayout) for Body Fragment to switch with other Fragments on button clicks-->


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/menuFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    class="it.anddev.bradipao.janus.MenuFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fr_menu">
</fragment>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end" />
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MesZt.jpg)

I want my height and width to be a percent of the phone height and width like shown here.

Comment: I think in the screenshot its a Widget, and not an app per say.

Answer (score 1):

You should use LinearLayout as a container, and use these properties:

- weightSum in LinearLayout, set it to 1.
- layout_weight in every child of the LinearLayout. For example:

  ```
  <LinearLayout
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:weightSum="1">

       <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.75">

            ....

       </LinearLayout>

       <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25">

           ....

      </LinearLayout>

  </LinearLayout>
  ```

First layout will take 75% of the screen and the second 25%.

Note that when using weights, height and/or width has to be 0dp. You can now make it as complex as you need.

Comment: For some reason this is not working for me... When I follow this approach my app layout is not set to a consistent percent of the screen... For example when I touch buttons in my menu fragment, new fragments fill the container in my framelayout. Each time a new fragment appears with a button touch, the app width and height stretch to different percents of the screen height and width. Does what I explained make sense?